# Is it possible to create a magnetic particle cloud?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I want to create a cloud of magnetic particles that will levitate in an electromagnetic field with an electromagnet. Is that possible? Is it easy to do or has it been done? I already have the magnetic nanoparticles and I just want to levitate them to form a 'cloud' so that each particle will stand in the air at specific distance from the others. They have the same size/weight. Would that be a problem? They need to sit in the air with specific distance between each other. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afQW8FT02DM . plasma, ie, ionized neutral gas  , has magnetic properties. The plasma ejected from the sun carries a magnetic field.https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2016/understanding-the-magnetic-sun

Comment: @annav   Obviously you only read the title and nothing else. I have specific magnetic nanoparticles that I want to create a cloud with, not other or any nanoparticles!

Comment: your question is not clear on that you alrady have the magnetic nanoparticles. Turn them into a plasma by ionizing them

Comment: http://www.splung.com/content/sid/6/page/phasesofmatter

Comment: Right, but when you say  _Is that possible?_ followed by _The particles **will** be nanoparticles_, I took that to mean a hypothetical situation.  Can you see my point?  Sure, I often misread posts, but your question reads a bit whatiffy....

Comment: @annav Even now, you don't give me a useful answer, I cannot make nanoparticles into a plasma! It will destroy them! And I dont really want to have a plasma, I just want a cloud of my nanoparticles! Like a static cloud of aerosol.

Comment: What have you tried by way of experiment yourself? It would be good to include that in your answer.

Comment: look at the phase diagram  in the link, you need a gas which means manipulating temperature , if you do not want ionization keep in the region of the phase diagram where it is a simple gas of nanoparticles.(dust?)

Comment: What about to load the particles electrostatical? If this would work in your experiment please not forget to leave a message. I'm very courious about your experimental setup.